# Display Account field values in Patient Card

Tags: health-cloud

I'm working on a health cloud implementation. I need to display some Account fields in Patient Card. I can see in all documents, the Patient card is used to display data from child objects but when I try to do the same for custom fields of Account, it's not getting displayed.

How can I display Account field values in Patient Card?

Comment: What does your configuration look like in the Patient Card Configuration object?  In particular, what field are you using as a Lookup to the Account object?  Is it a required field?

Answer (score 1):

My question was deleted but now I am posting a solution that might help.

1. Object Manager > go to Contact > create a new formula(checkbox) field
2. Fieldlabel: isVisibleOnPatientCard
3. Then go to Patient Card Configurations clic New
4. On the field Override Filter Field past the API name (e.g. isVisibleOnPatientCard__c - see the image)
5. Save and then it should appear on your Patient Card

[image]